# Why does my Rails AJAX delete method only work if I refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I just incorporated the DESTROY method for items in my school project. It worked fine, but now I must use AJAX to complete the action. After implementing this code, it only displays on the browser when I refresh the page, and not instantly when I delete an item. If I did not include enough information please let me know.

**_item.html.erb**

```
<% item.each do |i| %>
  <p><%= i.name %> | <%= link_to "Complete", i, method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %></p>
<% end %>
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
<% if @item.destroyed? %>
  $('#item-' +<%= @item.id %>).hide();
<% else %>
  $('#item-' +<%= @item.id %>).prepend("<%= flash[:error] %>");
<% end %>
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(params.require(:item).permit(:name))

    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "The item was added to your list."
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was a problem creating your item."
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])

    if @item.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@item.name}\" was completed and destroyed."
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error completing the item."
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: Where is you jQuery AJAX call?

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces I thought it gets passed through the HTTP request?

Comment: what I mean is the part of the code that contains :http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I have never seen this before, where is that supposed to go?

Comment: That function is the jQuery function that is responsible of creating an AJAX call. If you really use jQuery for AJAX in your project, there is certainly a part of your code that contains that function. In the link i gave you, there is full explanation of this function parameters and by tuning them you can control AJAX. (For example, using `complete` help declaring the function to be called when the request finishes)

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces - form has remote option set to true - it will automatically make an AJAX request without any additional js code.

Comment: @BroiSatse,  but I feel we need to see the body of the success handler. Am  I wrong?

Comment: I believe the issue is with my link.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces - The server will respond with a javascript script which is to be called on the client-side on success. This is what is being built within `destroy.js.erb` file. :)

Comment: @JonathanMusso - do you see any errors in the console? Also check the network tab to see what has been returned by the server (it might be 500)

Comment: I never used rubyon rails, but I feel OP should show us the code inside the second parameter of `link_to` so that we see the handler on complete.good night

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces - second parameter is just an object and it is used to generate the url for the link. There really is no need for more code in rails to make successful AJAX calls.

Comment: @BroiSatse Rails trace everything is working fine. In chrome inspector no errors. I believe in my loop I have done something wrong, I should not use 'i'.

Comment: @JonathanMusso - can you see the server response to the call in the network tab? My experience would be that it is not piggy-backing the method param correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash sets the message for the next request, this is why it works correctly in your create action (because you are redirecting). In your destroy action, you are rendering (which is not good, since it means delete request gets resent on page refresh, you should be redirecting here too) and setting flash, so it shows up on next request (refresh). If you want to send message for the response to the current request, you have to use [flash.now](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now) :

```
flash.now[:notice] = "\"#{@item.name}\" was ..."
```

Again, you should use flash and redirect on success and use flash.now and render on request failure.

**EDIT**:

***The above paragraphs only apply to html requests. I initially missed the point of the question!*** Thanks [BroiSatse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336231/broisatse)

Looking at your display code, you dont seem to be setting the `"#item-@item.id"`, so your return js does nothing. Add it like this:

```
<p id="item-<%= i.id %>"><%= i.name %> | ...
```

Comment: 'which is not good, since it means delete request gets resent on page refresh' - agree for the html format, not for js. Flash is set automatically, and will be removed after the next request - it is available straight away though.

Comment: yes, right, I completely missed the request being js before editing the answer. I guess the first part of my answer is moot now. Thanks!

Comment: Good spot in the edit - you need to use erb syntax though instead of interpolation.